# How to use filelink title instead of filename

Tags: typo3

i want to show the title of a file instead of the filename.

**version 6.0.14**

my typoscript:

```
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.20.wrap = <span class="csc-uploads-fileName"><i class="fileicon-"></i>|</span>   

tt_content.uploads.20.itemRendering.30.if.isTrue.field = true
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.10.file.width = 80

tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.40.bytes.labels = Byte | KB | MB | GB
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.40.wrap = <span class="badge">|</span>
```

i tried

```
tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.20.data = file:current:title
```

but i wont to show the filename if the title is empty. i dont know how to do it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using Version 6.x use:

```
 tt_content.uploads.20.renderObj.20.data = file:current:description // file:current:name
```

if you are using an older version try to use that (not tested but should work):

```
tt_content.uploads.20.labelStdWrap.override.if.isTrue.data = register:description
tt_content.uploads.20.labelStdWrap.override.data = register:description
tt_content.uploads.20.labelStdWrap.insertData = 1
```

Comment: i want to override the data only if the title is not empty.

Comment: thats exactly what this is supposed to do. Did you try it? for file:current:description you can of course use file:current:title. if you look at the first line for typo3 6.x (which I assume you are using) it always uses the description or title if you want and only if thats empty typo3 is using the file:current:name (which is the filename) indicated by //

Comment: as for the 4.x version the behaviour should be the same in the end as the filename is the default and the override is only applying if the description is set, hence the if.isTrue on the override object